# Filling ListView from Database

Tags: android

In the main Activity I have defined buttons and put them onclicklistener. The problem is in the viewAll button when I want to fill the list view from the database So that I call the method db.getAllContacts() but the code does not work

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnViewAll=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
if(view==btnViewAll) {
        if(name.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || phone.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
        {
            showMessage("Error", "Please enter all values");
            return;
        }
      else{
          List<Contact> contact = new ArrayList<Contact>(); 
          contact= db.getAllContacts();     
          ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contact); 
          ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.List);
          listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}

    public void showMessage(String title,String message)
    {
        Builder builder=new Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }
    public void clearText()
    {
        name.setText("");
        phone.setText("");
    }
```

In the SQLiteHelper file :

```
   public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM contact";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhone(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }// return contact list
    return contactList;}
```

Please help me

Comment: Use a cursoradapter instead.

Comment: You should use customAdapter for your contact list

Comment: And check log of getAllContacts() method that it returns the list of contacts or not from database

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:-

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contact);

and add this :-

ContactListAdapter contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_list_item,contact);

ContactListAdapter Class :-

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Contact> contactlist;

public ContactListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<Contact> contactlist) {
    super(context, resourceId, contactlist);

    this.context = context;
    this.contactlist = contactlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView contactId;
    TextView contactName;
    TextView contactPhone;


}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
         holder.contactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_id);
        holder.contactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
        holder.contactPhone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
     holder.contactId.setText(contactlist.get(position).getContactId());
    holder.contactName.setText(contactlist.get(position).getContactName());
    holder.contactPhone.setText(contactlist.get(position).getContactPhone());


    return view;
}
```

}

and contact_list_item.xml :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="test"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="test"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_phone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Thank you .. but This code give me error : 
ContactListAdapter contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_list_item, contact);

It say the constructor is not defined

Comment: Check your 3 parameter which you are passing in constructor.These all are returning required value  or not. which I defined in ContactListAdapter class

Answer (score 0):

The database access object logic is fine. The main problem is in the array adapter. You should try to implement ListAdapter in your Activity instead of using that ArrayAdapter

Comment: Can you help me how can I do this? I am a beginner

Comment: change listContent.setAdapter(adapter); to           listContent.setAdapter(this);
the IDE should prompt you to implement ListAdapter in the Activity.

Then implement the method according to the documentation